# Find the values of m that x^2 - 4mx +20 = 0: has a) no solutions and b) 2 solutions

Tags: quadratics

I understand how to solve this problem, but my method/logic seems a round-about way of doing so. Any tips on how to solve this question faster/more easily would be appreciated :)

Solving for part a) no solutions:

Find the discriminant: 16m^2 - 80

For no solutions: 16m^2 - 80 < 0

When 16m^2 -80 = 0, m = 5, -5. The interval between 5 and -5 is either below the x-axis (less than 0, i.e. no solutions) or above the x-axis (more than 0, i.e. 2 solutions).

Substituting a random number (0) between 5 and -5 into the discriminant gives -80 (less than 0) so we can confirm that **-5 < m < 5** is the range of m required to give no solutions.

For part b) I apply the same logic, so 2 solutions obtained when m < -root5 and m > root 5

This is from the Cambridge Methods Unit 1 textbook.

Comment: You went off the rails early: $16m^2 - 80 = 0$ gives you that $m^{\color{red}2} = \pm 5$, not $m = \pm 5$.

Comment: @John Hughes you probably meant $m^2 = 5$

Comment: Why substitute numbers to check the sign?  You have theorem on the sign of a quadratic polynomial

Comment: Indeed, peek-a-boo, I did mean that. Need more coffee. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use the *reduced* discriminant $\Delta'=4m^2-20=4(m^2-5)$.
 Next, there are no roots, as you said, if and only if 
$$\Delta'<0\iff m^2<5\iff |m|<\sqrt 5\iff  -\sqrt 5<m<\sqrt 5.$$
Similarly for the existence of two roots: it amounts to solving $|m|>\sqrt 5$.